# The identifier that starts with ...... is too long. Maximum length is 128

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am shifting my database to MS SQL Server 2008 R2, When I am trying to save long length string then it is giving me the error for Maximum length, while i have set the datatype of that column as "text" after it i replaced it with "varchar(max)" but no solution there.

kindly provide me a solution how to resolve this issue. I am executing the following query:

```
update hotel 
set hotel_policy = 
    "Overview of Park Central New York - New York
    This hotel is making improvements.
        The property is undergoing renovations. The following areas are affected:
        Bar/lounge
        Business center
        Select guestrooms

    Every effort will be made to minimize noise and disturbance.
    Occupying a Beaux Arts building dating to 1927, Park Central New York Hotel is within a block of famed concert venue Carnegie Hall and within a 5-minute walk of Manhattan’s world-renowned Broadway theater district. Prefer the great outdoors to the Great White Way? Central Park is just 3 blocks from the hotel. There, you can rent a rowboat at the lake, play a game of tennis, or visit the Central Park Zoo. The international boutiques and flagship department stores of Fifth Avenue start within a 10-minute walk of the hotel. For travel to sights farther afield, there are 7 subway lines located within 3 blocks of the Park Central.
    The hotel has a snack bar for guests' convenience, and coffee and tea in the lobby.
    Retreat to your guestroom and sink into a bed with a pillowtop mattress and down comforter and pillows. Need to check email or finish up some work? You’ll find a desk with an ergonomic chair and wireless high-speed Internet access (surcharge). Unwind with a video game (surcharge) on the flat-panel HDTV."

where hotel_id = 1
```

I search it a lot but the solutions i found are not useful to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

According to ANSI SQL standard, double quotes are used (if *necessary*) for object identifiers (ex. `UPDATE "hotel" ...)` and not as string delimiters (`"Overview of Park Central ..."`).  SQL Server has this behavior when `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is `ON`.

**Edit 1:**
The usage of single and double quotation marks as delimiters for object identifiers (including column aliases) is described below:

```
                        Delimiter   Delimiter
                        for         for
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER   Object ID   Alias ID        StringDelimiter
ON                      " or []     " or ' or []    '
OFF                     []          " or ' or []    " or '
```

- `ON` then double quotes can be used as delimiter for object identifiers (including column aliases) and single quotes are used as delimiters for string literals and/or for column aliases (`SELECT Column1 AS 'Alias1' ....`)identifiers.
- `OFF` then double quotes can be used as delimiter for columns aliases (`SELECT Column1 AS "Alias1" ...`) and as delimiter for string literals (`SELECT "String1" AS Alias1 ...`). Single quotation marks can be used as string delimiter and as delimiter for column aliases (`SELECT Column1 AS`Alias1`...`).

Use instead single quotes:

```
update hotel 
set hotel_policy = 'Overview of Park Central ...'
where hotel_id = 1
```

Answer (score 16):

If you don't want to change double quotes to single quotes add following two lines in the begging of the  script

```
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep the text in single quotes and escape quotes inside with two single quotes.

Answer (score -1):

```
 [ UPDATE denomination SET currencyType ='COINS', denomination ='1.00', currencyValue='3CAD', Active ='N', UPDATEDBY ='EBIX_ADMIN', UPDATEDDATE =GETDATE() WHERE groupId ='EXC' AND COUNTRYCODE ='CA' AND currencyCode ='CAD' AND denomination ='1.00' , UPDATE denomination SET currencyType ='COINS', denomination ='1.00', currencyValue='2CAD', Active ='N', UPDATEDBY ='EBIX_ADMIN', UPDATEDDATE =GETDATE() WHERE groupId ='EXC' AND COUNTRYCODE ='CA' AND currencyCode ='CAD' AND denomination ='1.00' , UPDATE denomination SET currencyType ='COINS', denomination ='1.00', currencyValue='2', Active ='Y', UPDATEDBY ='EBIX_ADMIN', UPDATEDDATE =GETDATE() WHERE groupId ='EXC' AND COUNTRYCODE ='CA' AND currencyCode ='CAD' AND denomination ='1.00' , UPDATE denomination SET currencyType ='NOTES', denomination ='7.00', currencyValue='8', Active ='N', UPDATEDBY ='EBIX_ADMIN', UPDATEDDATE =GETDATE() WHERE groupId ='EXC' AND COUNTRYCODE ='CA' AND currencyCode ='CAD' AND denomination ='7.00' , UPDATE denomination SET currencyType ='NOTES', denomination ='10.00', currencyValue='TENCAD', Active ='Y', UPDATEDBY ='EBIX_ADMIN', UPDATEDDATE =GETDATE() WHERE groupId ='EXC' AND COUNTRYCODE ='CA' AND currencyCode ='CAD' AND denomination ='10.00' , UPDATE denomination SET currencyType ='NOTES', denomination ='20.00', currencyValue='TWENTYCAD', Active ='N', UPDATEDBY ='EBIX_ADMIN', UPDATEDDATE =GETDATE() WHERE groupId ='EXC' AND COUNTRYCODE ='CA' AND currencyCode ='CAD' AND denomination ='20.00' ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Also how is this code related to the question? Are you asking a different one?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).