# The identifier that starts with … is too long. Maximum length is 128

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a problem. I try to create a database backup of a local database.

When I start the program in VS everything is fine because path to database is less than 128 characters. However, when I publish and install the app, path is more than 128 characters in length and I get that error.

On the Internet I found two solutions:

1. To use a single quote
2. To set: `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` & `SET ANSI_NULLS ON`

but whichever combination I try, I cannot get it right.

Can anyone tell me how to get it right?

My code:

```
internal void CreateDbBackup(string DbBackupPath)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    SqlCommand GetDataFile = new SqlCommand();
    GetDataFile.Connection = con;
    GetDataFile.CommandText = "select physical_name from sys.database_files where type = 0";

    con.Open();
    string YourDataFile = (string)GetDataFile.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();

    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = string.Format(@"BACKUP DATABASE [" + YourDataFile + "] TO  DISK = N'{0}' WITH  INIT ,  NOUNLOAD ,  NOSKIP ,  STATS = 10,  NOFORMAT", DbBackupPath);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Can you shorten the path to 128 characters or less?  That would seem to be the simplest solution.

Comment: change your `cmd.CommandText` = to the following
`cmd.CommandText = string.Format(@"BACKUP DATABASE [{1}] TO  DISK = N'{0}' WITH  INIT ,  NOUNLOAD ,  NOSKIP ,  STATS = 10,  NOFORMAT", DbBackupPath, YourDataFile);` learn to use the string.Formatting {}` properly and choose a shorter file path or upgrade the project to use .net `4.6.x`

Comment: I changed command text, and upgrade project  to .NET 4.6.1. but still getting that error.

I don't know how to shorter path, because when I publish and run it to install, it don't offer me to chose installation path :/ 

every other communication with database I use VS dataset environment (add query to table adapter) and this all are working, i even try to make stored procedures to do backup, and than call it, but i think i did wrong sintaks:

Comment: `CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateDbBackup]
 @DbBackupPath nvarchar (200),
 @YourDataFile nvarchar (200)
AS
 BACKUP DATABASE [@YourDataFile] TO DISK = @DbBackupPath WITH INIT , NOUNLOAD , NOSKIP , STATS = 10, NOFORMAT
RETURN 0`


Error:  Database '@YourDataFile' does not exist.

Comment: this problem solved the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19604295

Answer (score 0):

When you select `select physical_name from sys.database_files`, you get a bunch of file names. The syntax for `BACKUP DATABASE` requires, after `DATABASE`, not a file name, but a database name.

Your file names include paths, and that causes the total path to be so long that it cannot be interpreted as a database name. If the path were less long, you'd instead get the error that no database with that name could be found. This would tell you more directly what you're doing wrong.

You should have the database name already from your connection string.

Comment: Solve my problem. I Install "Visual Studio Installer", and add Setup Project to my solution. With this project I made installer where I can select custom installation path of my main app. Now path is less than 128 character, and everything is working correctly.

I don't know how, and why, but I am happy :D